# Make VBScript check for a file with a certain word in it's file name and then find and delete that file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I was wondering if there is a way to make it so my vbs script can check for and delete any files with a certain word in it's name. This is what I have so far:

```
x=MsgBox ("Searching for any infected files...",64,"Search") 

DIM filesys
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists("C:\Documents and Settings\Name\Desktop\example.txt") Then
    WScript.Sleep 1500
    x=MsgBox ("Warning! A infected file was found!",48,"Warning") 
    filesys.DeleteFile "C:\Documents and Settings\Name\Desktop\example.txt"
    x=MsgBox ("File was deleted!",48,"File Deleted")
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    x=MsgBox ("This Computer is now clean!",64,"Hooray!") 
Else 
    WScript.Sleep 500
    x=MsgBox ("File not found! This Computer is clean!",64,"Hooray!")
End If
```

Is there also a way to make the username/file path work on any computer? I know it is

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Desktop\example.txt"
```

in batch, but is there something like that in vbscript? Is there also a way to delete files with ANY extension that have 'example' in the name as well?  For example:

```
filesys.DeleteFile "C:\Documents and Settings\Name\Desktop\example.anyextension"
```

Thanks so much! I hope you don't mind my huge amount of questions, I am just starting to code with VBS/VBScript and really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: I guess that you want writing something like a cleaner , so you can get inspired by this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832414/how-to-move-file-while-renaming-it-with-incrementation-if-the-file-exists-in-vbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExpandEnvironmentStrings` method returns an environment variable's expanded value.  Environment variable names, which must be enclosed between `%` characters, are not case-sensitive:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo "Current user name: " _
    & WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
WScript.Echo "Desktop folder: " _
    & WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Desktop"
```

---

All next code snippets pasted here unchanged from linked sources. Could become a starting point for any `VBScript` beginner. Inspire yourself at next huge script repository: [Script resources for IT professionals](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/).

---

Stolen from [Search for Files Using a Wildcard Query](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1ab41ec0-ad1d-4bc2-bdcb-992d169ee41f). Uses the `Like` keyword to search for all files on a computer that contain a tilde (`~`). However, read [`CIM_DataFile` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387236(v=vs.85).aspx) at MSDN:

> The following `VBS` code sample describes how to perform a standard
>   wildcard search on a datafile. Note that the backslash delimiters must
>   be escaped with another backslash (`\\`). Also, when using
>   "`CIM_DataFile.FileName`" in the `WHERE` clause, the `WMIPRVSE`
>   process will scan all directories on any available storage device.
>   This may take some time, especially if you have mapped remote shares,
>   and can trigger antivirus warnings.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from CIM_DataFile where FileName Like '%~%'") 

For Each objFile in colFiles 
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
Next
```

---

Here's a smarter and *faster* solution with comprehensive comments: [How Can I Delete Specific Files in a Specific Folder?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/09/26/how-can-i-delete-specific-files-in-a-specific-folder.aspx) at *Hey, Scripting Guy!* blog (next to ten years old):

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFileList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='T:\Act'} Where " _
        & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")

For Each objFile In colFileList
    If InStr(objFile.FileName, "current") Then
        objFile.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Of course, like most `WMI` scripts, this one can also be run against a remote computer.