# How do I add %USERNAME% in a path while creating a txt file in VBS?

Tags: vbscript

I'm coding a new VBS script, which should create a TXT file in the Documents directory. While with other inputs I used %USERNAME% for the User Name of the PC, the command "CreateTextFile" seems to want the real directory, without including any variables like %USERNAME%.

I'm kinda of new to this so I can't figure it out.

That's what I tried:

```
Dim objFS, objFile
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Demo.txt", true)
objFile.WriteLine("some sample text")
```

It should understand %USERNAME% as the UserName of the PC, but doesn't.

What I get as result is the program saying he can't find the directory C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make VBScript check for a file with a certain word in it's file name and then find and delete that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136645/make-vbscript-check-for-a-file-with-a-certain-word-in-its-file-name-and-then-fi)

Comment: @JosefZ that's very specific, but I don't see where the OP mentions anything about checking for a particular word in a file and deleting it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pick up environment variables in vbscript WSH script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904739/can-i-pick-up-environment-variables-in-vbscript-wsh-script)

Answer (score 0):

To get the desktop one uses

> **SpecialFolders Property**
>
> Returns a SpecialFolders object (a collection of special folders).
>
> `object.SpecialFolders(objWshSpecialFolders)`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> object WshShell object.
>
> objWshSpecialFolders The name of the special folder. (eg Desktop)

Environment strings are not expanded. You can pass an entire string containing environmental variables. EG `"%userprofile%\Desktop"`. This code lists all variables available https://pastebin.com/rrEyVxFd.

> **ExpandEnvironmentStrings Method**
>
> Returns an environment variable's expanded value.
>
> `object.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strString)`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> object WshShell object.
>
> strString String value indicating the name of the environment variable
>   you want to expand.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty longer drawn-out, which are appropriate but these are a couple examples - much easier:

```
Option Explicit

Msgbox CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

' or into a variable

Dim oShell : set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim UserName : UserName = oShell.UserName
Msgbox UserName

Set oShell = Nothing
```